# PL SQL Patterns Matching

Tags: regex, oracle, regex-negation

How to only interpret a particular word(e.g test) from a big string if it’s really “start of line + optional white space + test + space”.Also allow mixed case for the word ‘test’

Comment: What do you mean by "interpret" a word? That is not a SQL or database concept.

Comment: I meant match the word test that must be start of line + optional whitespace + test + space

Comment: "match" is also unclear. It seems you are reading input strings and you must output them, either unchanged or with some changes. It seems you must remove the word `test` unless it is the first word? What if the word `test`, not at the beginning of the string but further in the string, is followed by comma or by period, not by space? What if it is at the end of the string? What if the string does NOT begin with the word `test` - do you still need to remove it everywhere else? For computers and software, you need a 100% clear problem requirement, nothing should be left to guessing.

Comment: e.g:" TeSt this is how I am going to tEst going for" I want this output to be : "TeSt this is how I am going to going for"

Comment: @mathguy is giving a valiant effort but please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @mathguy I have a source code in which the word test should be only considered if it is in start of line + optional whitespace + test + space..If any other place test is other just ignore that.Hope this is useful

Comment: @XanderCage Provide some test data and the results you expect.  What version of Oracle?

Comment: test_find1(); //this should be removed as test is not followed by whitespace,
 test sample 1; //this is perfectly fine,
 TEST sample 2;//this is also fine as we ignore case,
 test1 hope this is will help test2; // only test2 should be removed from

Comment: @unleashed what should be done if we want to keep the entire line of a string only if word 'test' appears at starting of line.If it appears anywhere then the entire line should be removed

Comment: @XanderCage In your last example, it starts with test1 and you say it should be kept, but it is the word test but it is not followed by whitespace.  Can you clarify what is to be done here?

Comment: @unleashed There are multiple lines of a source code of clob data type.These source code passes through a pl/sql block after passing the lines having the word 'test' anywhere apart from beginning should be removed.So input is source code and I have to write something in the pl/sql block so that this happens

Comment: @unleashed Can't there be solution like this -: REGEXP_REPLACE (source_code,'^test.*', '',1,0,'m'); Here it searches for test in beginning if it finds then removes that line.I want exact opposite if start + whitespace then keep otherwise remove the entire line

Comment: @XanderCage I've updated my answer to use both a REGEXP_LIKE and REGEXP_REPLACE.  Not sure if you can do this in one function, but my example show uses of both to help get you moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Using REGEXP_REPLACE with all parms, you can...

1. Provide the value you want to affect
2. Provide the regular expression you want to find
3. Tell the function on what character to start
4. Tell the function which occurrence you want to replace
5. Provide additional modifiers, of which 'i' means use case insensitivity

This will work if you are looking to remove the second instance of test, or TeSt, or TEST.  You've not provided much in the way of examples and expected results.

```
-- Start test data
with test_data as
    (select 'TeSt this is how I am going to tEst going for' as test_string from dual union all
     select 'test hello everyone how are you test' from dual union all
     select 'test_find1();' from dual union all
     select 'test sample 1;' from dual union all
     select 'TEST sample 2;' from dual union all
     select 'test1 hope this is will help test2;' from dual)
-- End test data     
select test_string,
       CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(test_string,'^test\s+','i') THEN
                    REGEXP_REPLACE(test_string,'test','', 1, 2, 'i')
           ELSE NULL END AS result
from   test_data;
```

More on REGEXP_REPLACE [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions163.htm#SQLRF06302)

Comment: Thanks for this but this above example did not deal with beginning of line + optional whitespace and a mandatory whitespace after test

Answer (score 0):

I am using your input string as below

```
'    TeSt this is how I am going to tEst going for '
```

and intentionally keeping some white spaces in the beginning and end. Below code produces your desired output. Also as you mention, it will replace ALL instances of the word TEST without considering case.
I hope this helps.

```
  Select 
REGEXP_REPLACE(     --Using RegExp_replace
    ltrim(rtrim(    --Trimming the white spaces
        input1)),   --using the input
        'TEST',     --search criteria
        '',         --Replace with string
        2,          --Starting with which character (you mentioned first occerance should remain
        0,          --Replace all subsequent occurances
        'i')        --case in-sensitive
        from (
Select '    TeSt this is how I am going to tEst going for' as input1 from dual --this is your INPUT)
```

Thanks,
Santosh

Comment: what should be done if we want to keep the entire line of a string only if word 'test' appears at starting of line.If it appears anywhere then the entire line should be removed